# Python - How do I add the backslash characters when formatting a JSON string?

Tags: python, json, string

I have a list `['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux', 'corge', 'grault', 'garply', 'waldo']` and I have to take every item in the list and add `\"` as a prefix and `\"` as a suffix for my JSON string.

A sample JSON string is (my desired output): `"{\"Names\":[\"foo\",\"bar\",\"baz\",\"qux\"]}"`.

Also, Why do I have to put the `\` for a JSON string? The server rejects it when I send it without the backslash.

When I attempt this:

```
x = "{\"Names\":[{0}]}"
y = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux', 'corge', 'grault', 'garply', 'waldo']
z = ''
for item in y:
        z += "\"{0}\",".format(item)
x.format(z)
```

It doesn't work as I wanted it to with the backslashes.

Comment: To avoid having to escape the quotes you could do `z += '"{0}"'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd stop trying to reinvent the wheel and use the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) instead:

```
import json

json.dumps({'Names': y})
```

More generally, you did not have to escape the double quotes here, had you used single quotes; the commas could have been handled by using `str.join()`:

```
z = ','.join(['"{0}"'.format(item) for item in y])
```

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> y = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux', 'corge', 'grault', 'garply', 'waldo']
>>> json.dumps({'Names': y})
'{"Names": ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "quux", "corge", "grault", "garply", "waldo"]}'
```

and

```
>>> ','.join(['"{0}"'.format(item) for item in y])
'"foo","bar","baz","qux","quux","corge","grault","garply","waldo"'
```

Comment: Ahh wonderful. Thank You. Didn't realize you can do all that from `json` module.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quirk of Python string literals, not JSON in particular. Since you are quoting the string literal with `""`s, any quotes **inside** the string have to be escaped with the backslash. You could avoid this by using single quotes around the string rather than double-quotes.